# The content type is not available in this site

Tags: content-type

I created a content type and deployed it as a feature. It shows up in the root site. I cannot attach it to the Task list in a sub site. I created a console app (code from MS) and tried to add it programatically. The message "The content type is not available in this site" appears. How can I make a content type available to a subsite? I thought it would be available by default to all subsites, especially being in the root. When I ran the console app, I was logged in as the system account on the SP server, so it shouldn't be a permissions thing. The content type has a parent of Workflow Task.

I have been struggling with this for over two weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the content type available to the task list in the sub site by adding the following to the feature.xml file:

```
<Properties>
    <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="True" />
</Properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to features and click the features/feature name/.feature and change the scope up from site to web and it should work fine.

[To improve my answer here is the MSDN on scope and content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454431.aspx)

Comment: Bummer. I get the error: "Elements of the type 'Content Type' are not supported at the 'Web' scope. This feature could not be installed.

Comment: To quote msdn I linked "Although you can create a content type with a Feature that is scoped either Site or Web, the scope must be Site if you are also provisioning files (such as document templates) with the same Feature."

Comment: ok. This is a pretty basic content type but it inherits from the Workflow Task type. I don't know if that is the problem. My content type is made up of an elements and feature xml file. I'll keep digging around. Thanks.

Comment: Got your link and it would have been helpful to state I am on MOSS 2007. Checked the same MSDN page but for 2007 and the web scope is "No".

Comment: One last thing. I am able to see and add the content type to the task list at the root level, just not any sites below.

Comment: I was able to make the content type available to the task list by adding the following to the feature.xml file: <Properties> <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="True" /> </Properties>                             Not sure why I would need that in there, but it seemed to work. Now I need to somehow figure out how to alter the task edit form so only the custom fields show up on the form.

Comment: Cool, when you have that its best to make your own answer ans post and check it as the way to do it with steps, so people can find it easier. Well done man.